# Extracting data that is relevant to the financial year as set by the parameter date

Tags: postgresql

I have a student_table and in this table there is a column student_financial_aid_type and the next column is date_ , so the value of student_financial_aid_type e.g. = 'direct' and the date_ 1/04/2018. I have used CTE tables and I have a parameter date at the beginning of the code, so that I get the number of students as of that day. e.g. my parameter date is 20/04/2019.

My financial year runs from april to march eg 1/04/18 - 31/3/19.

My question is where, it indicates that the student received some form of financial aid in the financial year, I will have an output column that says either 'Y' or 'N'. So using the example above, because the date 1/04/2018 is not in the financial year of the parameter date (20/04/19), it's actually in the previous financial year (1/04/18 - 31/3/19) then I would want this to be 'N' in the output column as in the financial year of the parameter date (20/04/19) the student did not receive any financial aid. However if I happen to change the parameter date 2/06/18, then the date that the student received the financial aid (1/04/18) is in the dame financial year as the parameter date, therefore my output column will now have 'Y' to reflect this. So however I do this it has to be dynamic and respond to the parameter date as that is the one that I as the user will be changing as and when

I have tried using date_part and I have managed to have the month number of the date that the student received the payout, from this point on I was thinking of using the month number as an indicator to what FY year it falls in, but I am not sure how to go about this.

```
WITH 
parameter_date as ( 

select '2019-04-26':: date p_date),

student_cohort as (select * from (
SELECT Distinct 
ms.studentid,ss.student_admission_date,ms.graduation_date


FROM master_student_table ms              
left join student_semeter ss on ms.student_id=ss.student_id , 
parameter_date, p 

AND ss.student_admission_date <= p_date -- i.e. began studies less than 
or equal to p_date
AND (ms.graduation_date is null or ms.graduation_date > p_date)) -- i.e. 
student finished studies more than p_date or IS NULL
)x  ),

student_finance as (select * from ( select  date_part('month', st.date_:: 
date)
date_part, st.date_, st.studentid,st.student_financial_aid_type                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
from student_table st
left join student_cohort s on st.studentid = s.studentid
where st.student_financial_aid_type in ('direct' , 'indirect')                                                                                                                      
) x )     


select distinct
s.student_id,                  
s.graduation_date,                 
s.admissiondate_date,                  
sf.date_,
-- this is what I would like it to be -- case when sf.date is in the same 
--financial year as the parameter_date 
--then 'Y'  else 'N' end was_financial_aid_received_in_the_fy,     
sf.date_part                                             

from

cohort s                                     
left join student_finance sf on s.student_id = sf.student_id and 
sf.student_financial_aid_type = 'direct'
left join student_finance sf1 on s.student_id = sf1.student_id and 
sf1.student_financial_aid_type = 'indirect' `
```

I would love for the output column 'was_financial_aid_received_in_the_fy' from the case statement, to have 'Y' if the sf.date_ that the student received financial aid is in the same FY year as the parameter_date and 'N' if this isn't the case

Thank you very much for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question basically boils down to the following:

1. Given a parameter date, figure out the financial year for that date.
2. Figure out if other dates fall in this financial year.

This is a great place to use dateranges, one of my favorite types.  We can figure out the financial year from the parameter date and use a daterange to represent it.  If the parameter date is before April, the financial year should be from April 1 of the previous year (inclusive) to April 1 of this year (exclusive).  If the parameter date is after April, the financial year should be April 1 of this year (inclusive) to April 1 of next year (exclusive).

Here's a query that should demonstrate how to do this:

```
WITH parameter_date as (
  select '2019-04-26'::date p_date
), fiscal_year as (
  select daterange(
        make_date(case when date_part('month', p_date)<4
                       THEN date_part('year', p_date)::int-1
                       ELSE date_part('year', p_date)::int END,
                   4, 1),
        make_date(case when date_part('month', p_date)<4
                        THEN date_part('year', p_date)::int 
                        ELSE date_part('year', p_date)::int+1 END,
                   4, 1),
        '[)') as f_year
  FROM parameter_date
),
test_data as (
  select test_date::date from (values 
    ('2019-04-01'),
    ('2018-04-01'),
    ('2019-03-02'),
    ('2020-12-01'),
    ('2017-05-26'),
    ('2020-02-27'),
    ('2020-04-01')
  ) v(test_date)
)
select test_date, 
       CASE WHEN test_date <@ fiscal_year.f_year THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as in_f_year
from test_data, fiscal_year;
 test_date  | in_f_year
------------+-----------
 2019-04-01 | Y
 2018-04-01 | N
 2019-03-02 | N
 2020-12-01 | N
 2017-05-26 | N
 2020-02-27 | Y
 2020-04-01 | N
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly and thanks for breaking down the logic...much appreciated